# Listing certain content type at top of view programmatically

Tags: views

I have a view which I am altering programmatically based on various parameters, using views_get_view , $view->set_item etc...

In the resulting view I want to be able to display a certain content type at the top, and other content types can flow as normal underneath. How can this be achieved?

Thanks!